# Lacie Rugged Thunderbolt 2 on iMac mid-2011

Tags: suspend, mac, thunderbolt

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.10 on my iMac mid-2011.
Everything is working well.
The only issue I have is with suspend when the Lacie Rugged Thunderbolt 2 is attached,
because the system goes in suspend, the disk led switches off, but after a few seconds it wakes up
and the system gets out of suspend state.
Do you have any idea about where to look for a solution?